# how to integrate OpenCameraApp in my project as a module

Tags: android, module, project, addition

I have integrated [This](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera) project as a module in my applictaion. When I am integrating, getting error as mentioned below. I have got so many links on SO suggesting me to downgrade studio version, or upgrade etc. Followed [this for adding module in my project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D9lYuRECoI).

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 
'E:\Softwares\sdk1\build-tools\25.0.3\llvm-rs-cc.exe' with arguments {-O 3 -
 I E:\Softwares\sdk1\build-tools\25.0.3\renderscript\include\ -I 
E:\Softwares\sdk1\build-tools\25.0.3\renderscript\clang-include\ -p D:\SVN-
WORKS\MyApplication\openCamera\build\generated\source\rs\release -o D:\SVN-
WORKS\MyApplication\openCamera\build\generated\res\rs\release\raw -target-
api 15 D:\SVN-WORKS\MyApplication\openCamera\src\main\rs\align_mtb.rs 
D:\SVN-WORKS\MyApplication\openCamera\src\main\rs\create_mtb.rs D:\SVN-
WORKS\MyApplication\openCamera\src\main\rs\histogram_adjust.rs D:\SVN-
WORKS\MyApplication\openCamera\src\main\rs\histogram_compute.rs D:\SVN-
WORKS\MyApplication\openCamera\src\main\rs\process_hdr.rs}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for the possible difficulties which you will face while adding a project as module/library in another application.

follow [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D9lYuRECoI) for adding a project as module/library.

Below are some points which you need to consider.

1. Change very first line of your build.gradle(library) from "apply plugin: 'com.android.application' " to "apply plugin: 'com.android.library' "
2. Remove applicationId from build.gradle(library)
3. Make sure build.gradle(app) and build.gradle(library) should be exactly same.
   like below

build.gradle(app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
      compileSdkVersion 22
      buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

      defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.xyz.xyzxyz"
         minSdkVersion 7
         targetSdkVersion 22
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    }

     dependencies {
         compile project(':openCamera')
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     }
```

*build.gradle(library)*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 7
         targetSdkVersion 22
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
 }
```

4. If both your application as well as your library module has the MainActivity and activity_main.xml file, then make changes either in app or library. Because you may get rumTime error like binary xml error at #40(lineNumber) etc.
5. Your android studio version and project level gradle dependency should have same verion. Like if your studio version is 2.3.1 then dependeny block should have " classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1' "
6. Last but not least,delete  tag of your library's mainActivity from library's manifest file. code looks like below. If you don't delete or comment it then two launchers will be there in your project and it will create two icons.

   ```
       <!-- Comment or delete tag to avoid two launchers in your application -->
       <intent-filter> 
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       </intent-filter>
   ```